# Hashlip generate less images than what I asked for

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, nft

Hi guys I'm using Hashlips [version: "1.1.1".]
https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_art_engine

I'm using it with Node JS ,to generate a collection of NFT's
I have inserted in the Layers folder 2 folders (45 Backgrounds, x 135 Shoes) and its suppose to give me 6075 images because 45 x 135 = 6075, but after generating 5615 images it stops and tells me on the terminal that if I want to be able to generate more unique images I need to add more layers ) but its false I'm supposed to be able to produce 6075 images I don't know where did I go wrong.

this is my Config.js file :

```
const basePath = process.cwd();
const { MODE } = require(`${basePath}/constants/blend_mode.js`);
const { NETWORK } = require(`${basePath}/constants/network.js`);

const network = NETWORK.eth;

// General metadata for Ethereum
const namePrefix = "Nft collection article Name example";
const description = "example NFT description ";
const baseUri = "ipfs://NewUriToReplace";

const solanaMetadata = {
  symbol: "EX",
  seller_fee_basis_points: 500, // Define how much % you want from secondary market sales 1000 = 10%
  external_url: "https://www.example.com",
  creators: [
    {
      address: "jdk3R0000EXAMPLEADRESSD0000oUKeB433SSh",
      share: 10000,
    },
  ],
};

// If you have selected Solana then the collection starts from 0 automatically
const layerConfigurations = [
  {
    growEditionSizeTo: 6075,
    layersOrder: [
      { name: "Background" },
      { name: "Shoes" },
    ],
  },
];

const shuffleLayerConfigurations = false;

const debugLogs = true;

const format = {
  width: 2048,
  height: 2048,
  smoothing: false,
};

const gif = {
  export: false,
  repeat: 0,
  quality: 100,
  delay: 500,
};

const text = {
  only: false,
  color: "#ffffff",
  size: 20,
  xGap: 40,
  yGap: 40,
  align: "left",
  baseline: "top",
  weight: "regular",
  family: "Courier",
  spacer: " => ",
};

const pixelFormat = {
  ratio: 2 / 128,
};

const background = {
  generate: false,
  brightness: "80%",
  static: false,
  default: "#000000",
};

const extraMetadata = {
  creator: "d3fco man",
};

const rarityDelimiter = "#";

const uniqueDnaTorrance = 10000;

const preview = {
  thumbPerRow: 5,
  thumbWidth: 50,
  imageRatio: format.height / format.width,
  imageName: "preview.png",
};

const preview_gif = {
  numberOfImages: 5,
  order: "ASC", // ASC, DESC, MIXED
  repeat: 0,
  quality: 100,
  delay: 500,
  imageName: "preview.gif",
};

module.exports = {
  format,
  baseUri,
  description,
  background,
  uniqueDnaTorrance,
  layerConfigurations,
  rarityDelimiter,
  preview,
  shuffleLayerConfigurations,
  debugLogs,
  extraMetadata,
  pixelFormat,
  text,
  namePrefix,
  network,
  solanaMetadata,
  gif,
  preview_gif,
};
```

For the first 5000 images everything goes well but I don't know why at  5615 it stops, I have tried again, and sometimes it produces a little bit more or a little bit fewer images.

but there are really 45 images, in the "background" folder.
(different drawings same size png's)

and there is really 135 images in the "Shoes" folder (different drawing but same size png's)

can you guy's Help me please ?
I have windows 10,
A lot of free space, (200 G's) and the latest Node Js version (v16.13.2)
my Hashlips is also the latest version: "1.1.1".
and this is the Github Repo of the code im using :
https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_art_engine

Comment: I don't have any experience in this library, but I'm curious with it. I will try to help you only for knowledge, but try to put this question as issue in the github or try to find any similar issue in the github.

Comment: great, thank you for your interest.
I went to the GitHub issues to see if there was someone whit a similar problem and didn't find anything similar, and I thought there would be quicker to find an answer here.

but your right I should put it in there, I'm doing it right now

Answer (score 0):

the problem was this line :

`const uniqueDnaTorrance = 10000;`

it was making the code stop after 10000 different DNA try's

the solution was to set up the uniqueDNATorrance to :

```
const uniqueDnaTorrance = Infinity;
```

so that the code can keep trying combination to reach the 6075 editions